# Reformat JSX in Atom

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor, jsx

I have some JSX written which I have been using the `Beautify` Atom plugin to format.  It doesn't appear to format the JSX very intelligently so I installed this [plugin](http://orktes.github.io/atom-react/#jsx-reformatting).  Only after highlighting some JSX, `cmd-shift-p`, and selecting `React: ReformatJSX` nothing at all happens.  If it were one long line of JSX, it would remain one line.  If it were the stupidly formatted JSX resulting from the `Beautify` formatting, it would remain that way.